# installing jupyterlab extensions on notebook startup

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, jupyter-lab

Every time my notebook shuts down and restarts, I lose the plugins and have to reinstall them from the terminal 
Is there a way to set jupyterlab extensions to be installed automatically on starting my sagemaker notebook?
The plugin I'm trying to install is:

```
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Any insight would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Lifecycle Configuration can be used to install a extension every time your Notebook Instance starts up.

There are sample Lifecycle Configuration scripts for installing a JupyterLab extension [1] as well as an NBExtension [2] that can be used for this purpose.

[1] https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-lab-extension/on-start.sh

[2] https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/install-nb-extension/on-start.sh

Comment: I tried following the lab extension one, but it keeps failing on start due to it taking more than 5 mins to start. Investigating the logs did not reveal anything untoward. Should i increase the timeout for notebook start?